# Passing Smarty variable to object parameters

Tags: php, variables, smarty, smarty3

I am using the Smarty engine and I want to pass a Smarty variable to an object argument.

My *index.php*:

```
<?php 
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->registerObject('articles',$articles);

if (isset($_GET['task'])){
    $smarty->assign('articleid',$_GET['id']);
}
```

My class for edit article:

```
   public function editArticle($id) {

       // database connection
       $conn = parent::Db();
       $q = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id ');
       $q->execute(array(':id'=> $id ));
       $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
       ....
   }
```

I want *id* for my function and my tpl:

```
{if isset($smarty.get.task) && $smarty.get.task eq articleedit} 
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header"> <h3 class="box-title">Bordered Table</h3></div>
    <div class="box-body">

            {articles->editArticle p1=$articleid }

    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

How can I pass an argument to my object? I read the Smarty document and it suggested this line :

```
{articles->editArticle p1=$articleid }
```

but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you should do:

```
$smarty->registerObject('articles',$articles);
```

In Smarty you should do:

```
{articles->editArticle($articleId)}
```

If it does not work, you should add more code how you assigned variable to Smarty.